# I can't change my profile on "meta.english.stackexchange.com"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I just do not have any "edit" button neither option to change my "about me" from another stackExchange site.

Is that bug or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile is copied from the main site. Simply click on the [main user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10100/genesis) link under your gravatar and edit your data there.

This behavior is the same on all Stack Exchange metas except Meta.StackOverflow, which is technically a completely separate site from Stack Overflow proper.

Comment: sorry, it didn't updated imediatelly and I did not thought about caching ... thanks